# Meaning of a key as an argument to the Cacheable annotation

Tags: java, spring, caching, spring-cache

I am trying to use the Spring `@Cacheable` annotation.

Lets look at:

```
@Cacheable(value = "employee", key = "#surname")
public Person findEmployeeBySurname(String firstName, String surname, int age) {

    return new Person(firstName, surname, age);

}
```

Am I right that if I add 2 people with the same surname then only one will be saved in the cache, and the method will return incorrect results sometimes?

When should I specify this argument?

How does spring create the key if I don't specify it explicitly(as I understand I should know it when I use CasheEvict and CashPut annotations)?

Comment: It's all explained in the documentation: http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#cache-annotations-cacheable

Comment: @JB Nizet how many SO questions about spring framework doesn't cover by reference documentation?

Comment: I haven't computed any statistics. What's your point?

Comment: @JB Nizet my point that documentation almost always cover any SO question. Nevertheless SO has wider audotiry because concrete answer can be found here faster

Comment: Then search for your answer in the documentation (It's as easy as opening it, hitting Ctrl-F, type Cacheable, and click on the TOC link), ask your question, and answer it immediately. Asking here and hope that someone with look for the documentation for you and copy/paste the documentation just shows a lack of research.

Comment: @JB Nizet I have read documentation. I am trying to check things which I am not sure to understand properly.

Answer (score 0):

JB Nizet is right, it is clearly in the documentation he linked to!

> [35.3.1 @Cacheable annotation](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#cache-annotations-cacheable) ...
>
> Default Key Generation
>
> Since caches are essentially key-value stores, each invocation of a
>   cached method needs to be translated into a suitable key for cache
>   access. Out of the box, the caching abstraction uses a simple
>   KeyGenerator based on the following algorithm:
>
> ```
> If no params are given, return SimpleKey.EMPTY.
> If only one param is given, return that instance.
> If more the one param is given, return a SimpleKey containing all parameters.
> ```

It is the last of the three cases that is importent for your mehtods, wihout cache parameter